# Color range over two layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, style

I am looking for a non-manual way to stretch a colour range over two raster layers.
Lets say I have two raster with data showing mean annual precipitation. In order to compare them visually I would like to stretch a colour range over both layers.
So in my case it should range from 320 - 900 and for example range from light blue to dark blue over both layers.

[image: symbology]

Comment: Save the symbology of one raster that you want for all rasters as a LayerFile. Then use the apply symbology tool to update the other rasters.

Comment: The LayerFile you create will have the colour ramp stretched over what ever you choose it to be, so you would need to set this to cover all ranges, e.g. 320 - 900. Then when you apply it the raster layer will adopt that range.

Comment: Excellent! Try it tomorrow and let you know what happens.